# Finding a result based on search query

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm hoping someone can help with this.

I have two sheets/tabs:

1. A Database tab that collects links using IMPORTXML.

   [image]
2. A spreadsheet that sorts the data.

   [image: 0]

What I would like to do is automatically categorise certain links from the database tab in certain columns to the sorting tabs.

For example, in column E of the sorting tab is Github. I'd like find the links for Github in the Database tab and sort these appropriately for the matching abbreviation - so I expect and MATCH and INDEX to be involved at some stage as row 1 in the Database tab isn't fixed - the abbreviations header may move.

I am expecting to have a function that searches for "GitHub" in a given search column and returns that cell to the Sorting tab, but I am unable to find a solution for this.

This is an example of the result that I am hoping to achieve, but the screenshot below isn't automated based on data pulled from IMPORTXML, which is the reason for this new spreadsheet.

[image: 0]

If anyone can provide help with this, that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

paste in **D2** cell and drag to the right:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(INDIRECT("A2:A"&COUNTA($A$1:$A))), IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A$2:$A, 
 SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TRIM(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(
 IF(Database!$A$2:$CG<>"", "♠"&Database!$A$1:$CG$1&"♦"&Database!$A$2:$CG, ), 
 LOWER(D$1)))<>"", 
 IF(Database!$A$2:$CG<>"", "♠"&Database!$A$1:$CG$1&"♦"&Database!$A$2:$CG, ), ))
 ,,999^99)),,999^99)), "♠")), "♦"), 2, 0)), ))
```

[image: 0]